# Hybirs - Category management - OOTB

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I am looking for a Hybris OOTB extension that gives users manage categories at ease.

1. Category creation or update
2. Expand and lookup for super and subcategories and its products (Basic tree view in BackOffice is extremely slow and not friendly)
3. Basic export functionality

Is there any cockpit or BackOffice extensions you recommend that I should take a look at.

Answer (score 1):

In the newer Hybris version you only have the backoffice. There aro no other cockpits anymore.

When you login in the backoffice you can choose a 'mask' at the top of the backoffice (for example the `Product-Cockpit`). But the masks are still in the backoffice.

You could implement your own `Category-Cockpit` mask where you can handle your use-cases.

Keep in mind that for the backoffice there is a own `Solr Config for Backoffice` index which is created to handle the belonging data in the backoffice fast. So maybe in your case it makes sense to add the categories here as well for faster access.

Comment: can you be specific which backoffice extension is helpful for better category management?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `platformbackoffice` and `pcmbackoffice` extensions. The Products view and Assortment view should be useful.

[image]